# How to convert ASCII(not single character, complete sentence) to string

Tags: python-2.7, ascii

I have method called 'encode(string_argument)' which converts string(sentence) to ascii and reverse it. I have to write method which decode the string.

Code:

```
str1 = 'This is sample text'

def encode(str1):
    encoded_str = ''
    for i in str1:
        encoded_str += str(ord(i))
    return encoded_str[::-1]

def decode(encoded_str):
    rev_encoded_str = encoded_str[::-1]
    # Incomplete

encoded_str = encode(str1)
decode(encoded_str)
```

Input for encode():
This is sample text

Output from encode():
6110211016112310180121190179511235115012351150140148

Input for decode():
6110211016112310180121190179511235115012351150140148

Output from decode():
This is sample text

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to add some separator in between each character while encoding, after that you can split the encode string by that separator and decode the string by chr() function.

Comment: Actually encoding function is not in our control we have to write decoding function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the solution:

```
def encode(str1):
    encoded_str = ''
    for i in str1:
        encoded_str += str(ord(i))
    return encoded_str[::-1]

def decode(encoded_str):
    reverse_string = encoded_str[::-1]
    temp_array = convert_to_possible_string_ascii(reverse_string)
    final_decoded_string = ""
    for x in temp_array:
        # print(str(chr(int(x)))+": "+x)
        final_decoded_string = final_decoded_string + str(chr(int(x)))
    print(final_decoded_string)
    return final_decoded_string

def convert_to_possible_string_ascii(str_array):
    temp_array = []
    temp_char = ""
    counter = 0
    for current_char in range(0, len(str_array), 1):
        temp_char = temp_char+str_array[current_char]
        counter = counter+1
        if counter==1:
            temp_var = is_valid_string_ascii(temp_char)
            if temp_var:
                temp_array.append(temp_char)
                counter = 0
                temp_char = ""
        elif counter==2:
            temp_var = is_valid_string_ascii(temp_char)
            if temp_var:
                temp_array.append(temp_char)
                counter = 0
                temp_char = ""
        elif counter==3:
            temp_var = is_valid_string_ascii(temp_char)
            if temp_var:
                temp_array.append(temp_char)
                counter = 0
                temp_char = ""          
    return temp_array


def is_valid_string_ascii(ascii_value):
    valid_list = list(range(65, 91)) + list(range(97, 123)) +[32]
    boolean_var = False
    if int(ascii_value) in valid_list:
        boolean_var = True
    return boolean_var

str1 = 'This is sample text'
encoded_str = encode(str1)
decode(encoded_str)
```

Comment: This code is only for alpha encode and decode. For alpha-numeric, we need to change accordingly in code.